# Is there any way to manually add some text on the codova splash screens with the IONIC framework?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I need help in adding the version number on the splash screen Images.
I am using the cordova splash screen with the Ionic frame work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using splash screen whilst your app is starting - the only way to show your version is to modify splash screen image.

I think you can "prolong" showing of the splash (with fetching the information you want) manually firing emulation of the splashscreen after real splash is hidden. Something like:

```
index.html
<div id="splashscreen" style="background-image: url(../img/splash.png);">
  <ion-spinner></ion-spinner> Loading...
  {{version}}
</div>
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){                
            $('#splashscreen').fadeOut();
        },1500);
    });
```

Of cource if you wan user to be waiting more just to show him a version # :)